# Convert Decimal-Number/MIB-Style Strings to Array Indices

Tags: php, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert mib-style strings into PHP array indices. The trick is that I have to do this for a variable number of strings. As an example:

```
$strings = ['1.1.1' => 1, '1.1.2' => 2, '1.2.1' => 1];
# Given the above, generate the below:
$array = [ 1 => [ 1 => [1 => 1, 2 => 2] ], 2 => [1 => 1] ] ] ] ]
```

I can't think of a way to do it that isn't just a brute-force, inefficient method. Any helpful function/approach/advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach since the problem/result you provide seems to be of a recursive nature. (You can achieve the same result with a loop, applying the same logic as the recursive function ofcourse)

So under the assumption that there are no conflicting string inputs/edge cases what so ever, the following could be one approach:

Loop over all the strings and their values, break it up and create a nested structure by passing the result array by its reference.

```
function createNested($pieces, $currentIndex, &$previous, $value)
{
    $index = $pieces[$currentIndex];
    // Our base case: when we reached the final/deepest level of nesting.
    // Hence when the we reached the final index.
    if ($currentIndex == count($pieces) - 1) {
        // Can now safely assign the value to index.
        $previous[$index] = $value;
    } else {
        // Have to make sure we do not override the key/index.
        if (!key_exists($index, $previous)) {
            $previous[$index] = [];
        }

        // If the key already existed we can just make a new recursive call (note one level deeper as we pass the array that $previous[$index] points to.
        createNested($pieces, $currentIndex + 1, $previous[$index], $value);
    }
}

$strings = ['1.1.1' => 1, '1.1.2' => 2, '1.2.1' => 1];

$result = [];
foreach ($strings as $string => $value) {
    // Break up the string by .
    createNested(explode('.', $string), 0, $result, $value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I realized I asked not quite the question I needed to (apologies!), but this does answer the question as-is and I think it's easy enough to modify for my needs. I really appreciate your help!